# How can I filter posts and post types by multiselect tags?

Tags: multi-select

I have posts and post types which using tags. In want to filter my post types by multiselect tag. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please specify the language you are using, and share the code that you have so far. I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :)